# How to fetch the key and values from response and store it in a json file using python?

Tags: python

I have a python code in this format that wants to fetch the key and values from response.

```
def test()
    data={u'Application': u'e2e', u'Cost center': u'qwerty', u'Environment': u'E2E', u'e2e3': u'aktest1', u'e2etest': u'aktest2', u'S68e2e': u'function',u'Application': u'test', u'Cost center': u'qwerty', u'Environment': u'E2E', u'e2e3': u'test7nov', u'e2etest': u'testapi', u'S68e2e': u'function'}

    new={}
    for k,v in data.items():
         new["key"] = k
         new["tags"] = []
    for d in v:
         flds = list(d)
         new["tags"].append({"key": k, "values": flds})
    print(new["tags"])
  with open(fileName, 'w') as f:
     json.dump(new["tags"], f, indent=3 * ' ')
test()
```

I am getting output as

```
 [ {'key': 'S68e2e', 'values': ['f']},
   {'key': 'S68e2e', 'values': ['u']}, 
   {'key': 'S68e2e', 'values': ['n']}, 
   {'key': 'S68e2e', 'values': ['c']}, 
   {'key': 'S68e2e', 'values': ['t']}, 
   {'key': 'S68e2e', 'values': ['i']}, 
   {'key': 'S68e2e', 'values': ['o']}, 
   {'key': 'S68e2e', 'values': ['n']}]
```

which is not correct.I expected to be

```
[{'key': 'Application', 'values': 'e2e'}{'key': 'Cost center', 'values': 'qwerty'}{'key': 'e2etest', 'values': 'aktest2'}]
```

Comment: If it is not correct then specify the expected

Comment: What does storing in a json file have to do with your question?

Comment: IMHO you should not use `new` as variable name, it is confusing.

Comment: @YugandharChaudhari, updated with the expected output. Thanks!

Comment: @anj It's ok not to specify `u` before every string, unless they have unicode codes in them.

Comment: @Guimoute Why would you ever specify `u` when working with Python 3? Every string is a unicode string there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension to create a list of dictionaries that wrap your key,values in other key values

```
[{ 'key': k, 'values': v } for k, v in data.items()]
```

Comment: Thanks It works. and How can I make to print the values even there are same keys and values again. This code is removing the duplicates.

Comment: @anj - This code isn't removing duplicates, you can't have multiple of the same key in a dictionary, the "removal" is being done when you're defining `data`. You should raise another question with what you've tried/researched if you have further questions